# Parent Controller class to call child overridden methods (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, oop, design-patterns, subclassing

I know this might seem anti pattern, and a lot will throw stones at me, but please hear me out.

I want to create a generic Controller to support many reference tables (mostly id, label). So I did something like this:

```
class GenericController extends Controller
{
    public function index($modelName)
    {
        $x = '\\App\\Models\\'.$modelName;
        $data = $model->all();
        return view('generic.list', ['model'=>$model, 'data'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

And this way my routes in `web.php` will be reduced to the minimum like this:

```
//List
Route::get('/{model}', function ($model) {
    return App::call('\App\Http\Controllers\GenericController@index', ['modelName' => $model]);
});
```

It's working very well with simple CRUD actions like store, update, etc.. However I know I am over simplifying the design because sometimes I need to return a field from a joined table in the index list for example. That's where I am heading into a dead end, sort of.

My first thought was to create a controller for each model that inherits from the GenericController like this:

```
class CategoryController extends GenericController
{
}
```

And whenever I need to override the GenericController method, I would simply add it to the child class. However how can I do this from inside the GenericController (call a method in a sub class from parent class)? Because otherwise I will have to create routes for every single model which is against my wish.

So basically I am looking for something like this:

```
class GenericController extends Controller
{
    public function index($modelName)
    {
        $x = '\\App\\Models\\'.$modelName;            
        //this thing I'm looking for is something like this:
        //Check if we have CategoryController and it has a definition for index
        //if yes do something like $data = CategoryController->index();
        //otherwise just call $data = $model->all();
        return view('generic.list', ['model'=>$model, 'data'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

So I know this seems weird and anti-pattern, but other wise how can I create my generic routes and controller actions?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is not really what is called "best practice". However, from a POO standpoint, it is an interesting question.

This what you can do:

```php
class GenericController extends Controller
{
    protected function getData(string $model)
    {
        return $model::all();
    }

    public function index($modelName)
    {
        $model = '\\App\\Models\\'.$modelName;  
          
        $data = $this->getData($model);

        return view('generic.list', ['model'=>$model, 'data'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

By default, the data will be retrieved "the simple way", using `$data = $this->getData($model);`.

However, if you make a `CategoryController`:

```php
class CategoryController extends GenericController
{
    protected function getData(string $model)
    {
        return Category::query()->with('something')->where('hello','world')->get();
    }
}
```

You will just have to override the `getData` method inside your `CategoryController`.

This is the way to go if you want something clean. Of course, your `categories` routes will have to use this `CategoryController` instead of the `GenericController`.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to avoid adding routes for implemented controllers and control everything from the generic controller and its routes. My solution so far is to initiate the CategoryController from inside `GenericController->getData()` method.

Comment: You can do this, technically it will work, but it is adding POO anti pattern on top of Laravel anti pattern... not ideal :p

Comment: I understand, this is all for abstraction and quick development for big projects.